# How to change state on browser refresh?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to make my app change state when I'm refreshing my browser but not when I'm just refreshing my states.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You're on the page /products/3, displaying the product 3, you hit refresh, then what should happen? What happens instead?

Comment: Refreshing your browser will cause the current state to be reloaded aswell. could you clarify?

Comment: I want something like this:
I have few siblings states:

- navigation.profile

- navigation.payments

- navigation.corrections

etc.

When page is refreshing I want always go to state navigation.profile when I'm on one of the siblings states.

Answer (score 1):

In the run function for the application you can call

```
$state.go('home'); // whatever state
```

and it will result in the app always going to the home state when you hit the refresh button.  Run is only executed when the app is loaded not on state changes.